# why is ready queue and block queue are stored in main memory?

Tags: operating-system

It is said that ready queue and block queues are stored in main memory. Some body please tell me why so. What are pros/cons if they are stored in secondary memory(hard disk).

Comment: If they were in secondary memory how would you start a task to read them in?

Comment: Let me flip it around: why *not* store them in memory? What do you think the pros would be of storing them on the hard drive? I can't think of any, and can think of many reasons it can't be done.

Comment: But why are suspended queue and job queue are stored in secondary memory. Ready queue and block queue can be accessed like these right?

Comment: The suspended queue and job queue aren't needed to run disk tasks.

Answer (score 1):

The ready and block queues must be stored in main memory as these are key/critical OS data structures.  *For stuff not stored in main memory, it must be paged in (and another page evicted) before it can be accessed by address* .  This is typically triggered by a page fault and is a blocking operation.  If your ready or blocking queues are not in main memory, then how can you block the current thread of execution and schedule another?  You can't.

Transferring data to/from secondary memory (such as a hard disk) is slow.  Preventing all other threads of execution from running during this period will seriously slow down the system.  Therefore the thread that generated the page fault is often blocked while transferring the data.

The thread may also block if all main memory-to-secondary memory data transfer channels are already in use, or if another thread is already transferring the page from secondary memory to main memory, or if the internal  structures that track which pages are in main memory are being manipulated.  (There may be other reasons too.)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you write a program, do you store your variables on hard disk?!
It is the same with an operating system. during run time, the operating system uses special data structures, like job queues, file-system structures, and many other types of variables/structures.
Any operating system... yet any software stores this kind of stuff in main memory because it is much faster than the hard disk. and the variables/structures are just needed in run time. hard disks are mainly used for "permanent" storage.

Comment: But you can have "virtual memory", where data belonging to an executing program temporarily resides on disk, when it's not actively being referenced.  However, parts of the operating system cannot be in "virtual memory", because they're needed to access the disk drives for "virtual memory", and they can't operate if they're "paged out".